# iOS Image editing open source library - or just some tips

Tags: ios, drawing, uiimage, core-graphics, editing

For an ios app I'm writing, I'd like to take an photo from the photo library and then let the user "clean it up", essentially deleting parts of it that are not needed. For example, suppose the user chooses a photo of a person, my app only needs the head and everything else should be deleted so the user needs to clean the photo up by deleting the background, the body or other persons in the photo.  Imagine a photoshop like experience but with only one tool - the eraser.

I'm looking for open source libraries, or examples or just tips of how to get started with that.

I know how to use a UIImagePickerController to select an image so the missing part is the actual editing. As a complete noob I'd be happy to get some advice on what would be a reasonable approach to this, preferably with some sample code or even a reusable library.

I suppose, in a high level, what I want to do is start with a rectangular image and make sure it has an alpha layer and then as the user touches parts of the image to delete them, I need to "delete" more pixels from the image by changing their alpha level to 0.  But that's a too high level description which I'm not even sure is correct... Another reasonable requirement is undo support.

Another approach that comes to mind is using the original image and a mask image which the user edits while touching the screen and when "done", somehow compile the two images to one image with alpha.  Of course, this is an implementation detail and the user need not know that there are two images on the screen.

If possible, I'd like to stay at the UIImage or UIImageView or Core Graphics levels and not have to mess with OpenGL ES. My gut feeling is that the higher graphics levels should be performant enough and easy to understand, maintainable clean code is a consideration...

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get well acquainted with Quartz 2D / CoreGraphics. This guide is a good start for you http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

The task you have described can be as simple or as complicated as you want. From letting the user use their fingers to erase the area around the photo by dragging their finger around (easy) to you trying to detect high contrast areas that help you guess where to cut (pretty complicated).

If you choose the former, you will essentially want to create a clipping mask based on user touches so have a look at the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded methods of UIView.

For the clipping mask, this is probably a good simple example to get you started [How erase part of UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526336/how-erase-part-of-uiimage)

Good luck with it, it sounds like a fun (if not challenging) project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm looking at the links you've posted, particularly this is very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487601/how-to-erase-some-portion-of-uiimageviews-image-in-iphone but I'll leave the answer as "not accepted" for a few more days to let folks post more answers and hopefully maybe even a library that does exactly that (slim chance). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be pretty easy, thanks for @Rog's pointers.
I'll paste my solution below. This goes in the controller code:

```
#pragma mark - touches

- (void) clipImageCircle:(CGPoint)point radius:(CGFloat)radius {
  UIBezierPath* uiBezierPath = [UIBezierPath  bezierPathWithArcCenter:point radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:2 * M_PI clockwise:NO];
  CGPathRef erasePath = uiBezierPath.CGPath;
  UIImage *img = imageView.image;
  CGSize s = img.size;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(s);
  CGContextRef g = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextAddPath(g, erasePath);
  CGContextAddRect(g,CGRectMake(0, 0, s.width, s.height));
  CGContextEOClip(g);
  [img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
  imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

- (void) receiveTouch:(CGPoint)point {
  NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
  [self clipImageCircle:point radius:20];
}

- (void) endTouch {
  NSLog(@"END TOUCH");
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  // We currently support only single touch events
  UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:imageView];
  if ([imageView hitTest:point withEvent:event]) {
    [self receiveTouch:point];
  }
}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self endTouch];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self endTouch];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:imageView];
  if ([imageView hitTest:point withEvent:event]) {
    [self receiveTouch:point];
  }
}
```