# Erase part of image and replace with background ios

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I create the application on iOS using Xamarain.iOS, where one of the functions is erase the object from a photo of room and insert another element on this place. The application is in the process of planning and I looking for some libraries that will assist. Currently I found only openCV, but I have a problem with binding it to Xamarin.iOS. Over the binding I am still working, but I wanted to know if there are any alternatives to openCV. I was very long time looking for any library that would assist and maybe someone knows a better option.
I want do something like this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-eraser-remove-unwanted/id839750800?mt=8

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is off topic: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.Consider reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether below sample is useful or not

https://github.com/craighowarth/WipeAwayView

It is used to erase the upper layer to reveal the underneath image or view.

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Thanks for answer and help, unfortunately this is not I'm looking for. If I good understood in this sample we can delete whole picture, but I want delete part of image and use some algorithm to restore background in this place.

Comment: Refer below link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487601/how-to-erase-some-portion-of-a-uiimageviews-image-on-ios